# undefined local variable or method `category' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rubygems

```
require 'csv'
    load 'dbconnection.rb'
    require 'activerecord'

    class Definition<ActiveRecord::Base

    end
    csv_definition = File.read('C:/definition.csv')
    spy_definition = CSV.parse(csv_definition, :headers => false)
    spy_definition.each do |row|
          Definition.create!(

                            :id => row[id],
                            :category => row[category],
                            :name => row[name],
                            :dangerlevel => [dangerlevel],
                            :description => [description]
                            )       

                    end
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
datainsertion.rb:26: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
datainsertion.rb:27: undefined local variable or method `category' for main:Object (NameError)
    from datainsertion.rb:24:in `each'
    from datainsertion.rb:24
>Exit code: 1
```

i need to load that csv file in to the database but i am getting this error.., help me guys to fix this issue.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require 'csv'
    load 'dbconnection.rb'
    require 'activerecord'

```
class Definition<ActiveRecord::Base
end
CSV.foreach("C:/definition.csv") do |row|
Definition.create!(
    :category =>row[0],
    :name => row[1],
    :dangerlevel => row[2],
    :description => row[3]
    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is really all you need. You have a variable category that hasn't been defined yet. Try 'category'.

Comment: i checked it also but it is rising an error as 


 `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: any more suggestions  @Aristata